# php- MySQL to JSON data redundancy

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to json_encode some MySQL rows. The json seems to have record twice.
JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "0": "15",
    "1": "dfgdfg",
    "2": "fgdfg",
    "3": "MyApp",
    "4": "0",
    "5": "2015-09-16 13:09:48",
    "6": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "RequestId": "15",
    "RequestEmail": "dfgdfg",
    "RequestName": "fgdfg",
    "RequestApp": "MyApp",
    "RequestGranted": "0",
    "RequestTime": "2015-09-16 13:09:48",
    "RequestGrantedTime": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
},
{
    "0": "16",
    "1": "dfghfg",
    "2": "sdfsfg",
    "3": "MyApp",
    "4": "0",
    "5": "2015-09-16 13:10:43",
    "6": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "RequestId": "16",
    "RequestEmail": "dfghfg",
    "RequestName": "sdfsfg",
    "RequestApp": "MyApp",
    "RequestGranted": "0",
    "RequestTime": "2015-09-16 13:10:43",
    "RequestGrantedTime": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
}
```

I don't need first 0-6 nodes for each field.
I've tried several ways to convert data row to json in my PHP file to no avail. these records with `"0" : "15"` still show up.

I'm using phpMyAdmin for MySQL database. Any way I can fix this? Right now its ok because data is less. But thats 100% overload to read for my clients.

Php code:

```
    function fetchDataForUser($userString){
             $selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM  `Invitations`";
             $result = mysql_query($selectQuery);
             if($result == FALSE){
                echo mysql_error();
             }

             echo "[";
             if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
                 $first = true;
                 $data = array();
                 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                 {
                     $data[] = $row;
                     if($first) {
                         $first = false;
                     } else {
                         echo ',';
                     }

                     echo json_encode($row);
                     //echo $row[0]. $row[1]. $row[2]. $row[3]. "\r";
                     //echo "{\"".$row[3][0]."\", \"".$row[1]."\", \"".$row[2] ."\"}";
                  }
                  echo "]";
              } else {
                  echo '[]';
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) docs, `$row` will contain both number indices and associative indices by default.

Try using `$row =`[`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)`($result)` instead.

Comment: Awesome!! That did it!